# How to add thousand separator to a String with JS or JQuery in this particular function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add thousand separators (;) to the output of the function below. There are 15 very similar functions in the project I am working on. All need the toFixed() functionality. I need to be able to manipulate how many decimal numbers is shown in the output. I am new to programming and JS! I tried to solve this using all similar solutions I found on Stack Overflow, but could not solve this alone yet. Can you pls provide a solution that will work with the function below. Thanks!

```
function changePictoryTaleYearRevenuesOutput(avg_number_spots, inv_cal_monthly_vps, avg_price_per_vps){
    var pictorytale_year_revenues = avg_number_spots * inv_cal_monthly_vps * avg_price_per_vps * ((12 / 1000000) / 0.771145238184416);
    $("#pictorytale_year_revenues").html(pictorytale_year_revenues.toFixed(0));
}
```

Comment: Have you looked into using the built-in method in JS to format numbers based on locales? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat

Answer (score 0):

You could reverse the string and use a regular expression then reverse again like this:

```
var mySeparatorRegex = /\d\d\d(?=\d)/g;
var myString = ...;
var myReversedString = myString.reverse();
var myReversedNewString = myReversedString.replace(mySeparatorRegex, function(val) {
  return val + ";";
}
var newString = myReversedNewString.reverse();
```

Answer (score 0):

[Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat) will do this, and you can set the precision, or turn it into a currency representation.

The Thousands separator varies by locale (country)
You mention `;` but for me in the en-US it is a comma `,`
Intl.NumberFormat will use the correct separator just by specifying the locale.

You can create one (or many) formatters in advance, or create them as needed.

```js
const en_formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', { maximumSignificantDigits: 8, maximumFractionDigits: 3 });
const en_currency = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', { style: 'currency', currency: 'USD' });

let value = 54321.123;

let formatted = en_formatter.format(value);
console.log(formatted);
let currency = en_currency.format(value);
console.log(currency);
```